# Truncated a text with ellipsis that be next to a title

Tags: css, ellipsis

I would like to have a summary next to a title and if the summary is too long, I would like it be truncated as classical ellipsis like that:

> **My Title**This is a very long text that I want to...

I don't want the width of the summary to be defined, I would like that it takes all the room on the same line. I tried to use `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` but I can not put the truncated text next to the title. If the text is next to the title, the summary is not truncated; if the text is truncated, it is not next to the title.

These are some of my attempts:

```
<h2 class="title">
  My Title
  <span class="tiny shortening">This is a very long text that I want to shorten This is a very long text that I want to shorten This is a very long text that I want to shorten This is a very long text that I want to shorten  shorten</span>
</h2>

<h2>
   My Title
   <div class="tiny shortening">This is a very long text that I want to shorten This is a very long text that I want to shorten This is a very long text that I want to shorten This is a very long text that I want to shorten </div>
</h2>
```

with css

```
.title {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inline {
    display: inline;
}

.tiny {
    font-size: 70%;
 }

.shortening {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: try moving the styles on .shortening into .title instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt43F/1/) for you. Indeed, as Brian Glaz said in the comments, move the `.shortening` styles to the `.title`. Also, I added a wrapper around the text, so that it knows how much width it may take up.

If you have any questions left, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I tried this solution but in fact no since I had the bad result

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on shortening like width:200px; without a cutoff there is no reason to truncate the text.

Comment: Yes, I was using this solution before to have the Sander's solution.